# Computing a Gaussian hypergeometric function

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, special-functions

I want to calculate the function `gg[m, x]` given by

```
gg[m_, x_] :=  Hypergeometric2F1[2 + m, 5/2 + m, 2 + 2 m, x^2]
```

in which `x` is between 1 and 0. I need to calculate this function with high values of `m` (`1000 <= m <= 2000`).

In some regions the calculation gives the result quickly. For example, when `x` is between 0, and .66, the speed of calculation is fast. Further, by using `$MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity`, I can calculate `gg` in the region `.8 < x <. 999` quickly, However, in the region `.72 < x < .80`, it gets very slow. At `x = .77` the calculation takes nearly a day to finish.

I want to know how can I eliminate this hindrance to my calculations.  I must mention that I give x as a rational number, say, 66/100 or 77/100, because I want to  avoid machine arithmetic.

Comment: Why is `a` a parameter of `gg` if it is not used in `gg`?  Might you have made an error in your definition?

Comment: `a`is probably `x`. But it is absolutely unclear, what do you ask?

Comment: Your function at least has a pole at `x=1`, going to infinity for every positive value of `m`: `Limit[gg[m, x], x -> 1, Direction -> 1, Assumptions -> m > 0]==Infinity`. So it is to be expected that it grows fast. Apart from that tabulating data from the function seems to work just fine here from what i can see.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Comment: @Amir Nasser To what precision do you need those numbers? Can you motivate for what application you need such high `m` values of your given function? Maybe this question could still be interesting to others in terms of optimizing function evaluation for performance. But i think it could use some motivation by understanding better what the problem is, that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown by [`@ChipHurst`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346/chip-hurst), `FunctionExpand` accelerates the calculations

```
gg1[m_, x_] =
  Hypergeometric2F1[2 + m, 5/2 + m, 2 + 2 m, x^2] //
   FunctionExpand;

N[gg1[2000, 77/100], 20] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.000321, 3.0916351054753710754*10^347}  *)

N[gg1[2000, 99/100], 20] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.000224, 4.7018876879700276638*10^977}  *)
```

Some additional speed - up can be made by simplifying the expression after `FunctionExpand`, and using [`arbitrary precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionCalculations.html) to avoid `machine precision` rather than applying `N` to exact evaluations. There is a small reduction in precision.

```
gg2[m_, x_] =
  Assuming[{Abs[x] < 1},
   Hypergeometric2F1[2 + m, 5/2 + m, 2 + 2 m, x^2] //
     FunctionExpand // 
    FullSimplify];

gg2[2000, 0.77`20] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.000081, 3.0916351054753711*10^347}  *)

gg2[2000, 0.99`20] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.000076, 4.70188768797003*10^977}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FunctionExpand` to express this expression in terms of elementary functions:

```
gg[m_, x_] = FunctionExpand[Hypergeometric2F1[2 + m, 5/2 + m, 2 + 2 m, x^2]]
```

[image]

```
N[gg[2000, 77/100], 20] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000261, 3.0916351054753710754*10^347}
> ```

```
N[gg[2000, 99/100], 20] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000203, 4.7018876879700276638*10^977}
> ```

```
Plot[Log10[gg[1000, x]], {x, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: A look at the elementary form of the function would at once tell me that numerical evaluation might become troublesome at $x\approx 1$, and that cleverness, arbitrary precision, or both would be needed in that case.

Comment: Shouldn't arbitrary precision be enough, because of precision tracking?

Comment: One might want to keep things entirely in machine precision (e.g. the function becomes embedded somewhere in a compiled function), for example.

Comment: thanks you very much. your answer is so helpful . FunctionExpand Function  works good